# Request dispatcher is throwing nullPointerException?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, tomcat7

I am using request dispatcher and it is throwing null pointer exception. I don't know why this is happening because I do have Map.jsp in root directory. Here's the code

LocationTrackerServlet.class

```
RequestDispatcher rd= getServletContext (). getRequestDispatcher ("/Map.jsp");// this is line 112
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

[image: Project Directory Structure]

Tomcat Error
[image: Tomcat Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the exception is throw in `GenericServlet` , it seems like servlet config is not stored in 
`GenericServlet`. It looks like you are overriding the servlet init method and missing a call to `super.init` to store the config in `GenericServlet`.

`GenericServlet` is extended by your servlet when it extends `HttpServlet`.

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {  
    super.init(config);
    //Your code  
}
```

Comment: Yup, that was the cause.

Answer (score 1):

why are using getServletContext ().getRequestDipatcher,

instead use request.getRequestDipatcher()

Comment: This works, but again why getServletContext ().getRequestDipatcher doesn't works.

Comment: getServletContext ().getRequestDispatcher() used to forward request to other application (Context) in same container...

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
RequestDispatcher rd= request.getRequestDispatcher ("/Map.jsp");
```

Instead of :

```
RequestDispatcher rd= getServletContext (). getRequestDispatcher ("/Map.jsp");
```

Answer (score -1):

use request.getRequestDipatcher()

Comment: correctly defined comments never effect functioning code, thats the point of them.

Comment: I don't have those comments in real, this is here only for others understanding.

Comment: @user3621470 no they definitely can not, post an example/ask question of where you think this happens. As they absolutely can not.